# Synchronization of queries to a MariaDB database

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, mariadb, race-condition

Because of some high-availability considerations, I design a system where multiple processes will communicate/synchronize via the database (most likely MariaDB, but I am open to looking into PostgreSQL and MySQL options).

One of the requirements identified is that a process must take a piece of work from the database, without letting another process take the same piece of work concurrently.

Specifically, here is the race condition I have in mind:

1. Process A starts a SQL transaction and runs `SELECT * FROM requests WHERE ReservedTS IS NULL ORDER BY CreatedTS LIMIT 100`. Here `ReservedTS` and `CreatedTS` are `DATETIME` columns storing the time the piece of work was created by a work submitter process and reserved by a work executor process correspondingly.
2. Process B starts a transaction, runs the same query and gets the same set of results.
3. Process A runs `UPDATE requests WHERE id IN (<list of IDs selected above>) AND ReservedTS IS NULL SET ReservedTS=NOW()`
4. Process B runs the same query, however, because its transaction has its own snapshot of the data, the `ReservedTS` will appear not null to Process B, so the items get reserved twice.
5. Process A commits the transaction.
6. Process B commits the transaction, overwriting the values of process A.

Could you please help to resolve the above data race?

Comment: I'd expect 6) to fail.

Comment: @jarlh, why? Is this specified somewhere? I would like to read more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that by using exclusive locks:

For simplification the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int not null auto_increment primary key, reserved int);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (0,0), (1,0);
```

Process A:

```
BEGIN
SELECT id, reserved from t1 where id=2 and reserved=0 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE t1 SET reserved=1 WHERE id=2 and reserved=0;
COMMIT
```

If Process B tries to update the same entry before Process A finished the transaction it has to wait until lock was released (or a timeout occurred):

```
update t1 set reserved=1 where id=2 and reserved=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (12.04 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And as you can see, Process B didn't update anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you check your table creation statement? It seems it is missing the field `a`, and then the insertion statement should insert something with `a=2` for the later queries to work.